# SQL How to use column that has been used in a pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Region:

| Region | RegionID |
| --- | --- |
| Americas | 1 |
| Europe | 2 |

Orders:

| OrderID | RegionID | Sales | Customer Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 | Corporate |
| 2 | 2 | 100 | Small Business |
| 3 | 2 | 200 | Small Business |

**I currently have**:

```
SELECT
    [Region Name],
    [Corporate] AS [Corporate Total],
    [Small Business] AS [Small Business Total]
FROM
(
    SELECT reg.Region AS [Region Name],
    ord.Sales,
    [Customer Type]
    FROM Orders ord
    JOIN Region reg ON ord.RegionID = reg.RegionID
) AS src
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Sales)
    FOR [Customer Type] IN ([Corporate], [Small Business])
) AS pvt1
```

Which outputs this:

| Region Name | Corporate | Small Business |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Americas | 200 | Null |
| Europe | Null | 300 |

What I need to do is have an output that displays a total sales for each region, as well as a percentage of total sales per customer type, such as this **desired result**:

| Region Name | Corporate | Corporate % of Total Sales | Small Business | Small Business % of Total Sales | Total Region Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Americas | 200 | 100 | Null | Null | 200 |
| Europe | Null | Null | 300 | 100 | 300 |

I've tried to do a sum of sales for the Total Sales column but nothing I've tried and looked up has worked. I'm not sure how to use the columns again to calculate the percent, and then the total sale amount for each region.

Comment: A pivoted column could take part in an expession as any other column e.g. `100.0*[Corporate]/([Corporate] + [Small Business]) as [Corporate % of Total Sales]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function `SUM() OVER ()` to get the total value to calculate the percentage.

```
SELECT
    [Region Name],
    [Corporate] AS [Corporate Total],
    [Corporate] * 100.0 / SUM([Corporate]) OVER() AS [Corporate % of Total Sales],
    [Small Business] AS [Small Business Total],
    [Small Business] * 100.0 / SUM([Small Business]) OVER() AS [Small Business % of Total Sales],
    [Corporate] + [Small Business] AS [Total Region Sales]
```

OR maybe this

```
SELECT
    [Region Name],
    [Corporate] AS [Corporate Total],
    [Corporate] * 100.0 / (ISNULL([Corporate], 0) + ISNULL([Small Business],0)) AS [Corporate % of Total Sales],
    [Small Business] AS [Small Business Total],
    [Small Business] * 100.0 / (ISNULL([Corporate], 0) + ISNULL([Small Business],0)) AS [Small Business % of Total Sales],
    [Corporate] + [Small Business] AS [Total Region Sales]
```

Comment: Was definitely over thinking this, however the percentage given in the output is not correct. I'm unfamiliar with the OVER () function

Comment: You wanted percentage of [Corporate] over (  [Corporate] + [Small Business] ) OR column wise ?